# Extending two instances of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, clone

I cannot extend this hierarchy of objects preventing things to mess up.
My HTML test file includes the following JS

```
(index.html)

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="granpa.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="father.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="child1.js"></script>
```

Granpa is a very simple object

```
(granpa.js)

var granpa = {
    myname: 'Granpa',
    mydata: {age: 80, salary: undefined}
};
```

This test focuses on "myname" variable. I included "mydata" just to point out the I need a **deeply recursive** object extension.

Father is like

```
(father.js)

var father = {
    myname: 'Father',
    mydata: {age: 50, salary: 30000}
};
```

Child 1 is similar, moreover it contains code to merge objects and display test data.

```
(child1.js)

var child1 = {
    myname: 'Child 1',
    mydata: {age: 19, salary: 15000}
};

/* I clone granpa to a temporary object, to be sure not to modify the original*/
var tmpGranpa = $.extend(true, granpa);

/* I clone father to a temporary object, to be sure not to modify the original*/
var tmpFather = $.extend(true, father);

/* Merge all: again producing a brand new obj1, to not mess up the originals */
var obj1 = $.extend(true, tmpGranpa, tmpFather, child1);

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('Check obj1 result: '+obj1.myname);
    console.log('Check granpa was not overridden: '+granpa.myname);
    console.log('Check father was not overridden: '+father.myname);
});
```

Output is

```
Check obj1 result: Child 1
Check granpa was not overridden: Granpa
Check father was not overridden: Father
```

Please, note that I used

```
$.extend(true, ...)
```

to perform a deeply recursive copy of objects, as jQuery manual suggests.

Everything is fine, as you see.
Now, let's add second child

```
(index.html)

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="granpa.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="father.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="child1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="child2.js"></script>
```

Child 2 file will be

```
(child2.js)

var child2 = {
    myname: 'Child 2',
    mydata: {age: 11, salary: 0}
};

/* I clone granpa to a temporary object, to be sure not to modify the original*/
var tmpGranpa = $.extend(true, granpa);

/* I clone father to a temporary object, to be sure not to modify the original*/
var tmpFather = $.extend(true, father);

/* Merge all: again producing a brand new obj2, to not mess up the originals */
var obj2 = $.extend(true, tmpGranpa, tmpFather, child2);
```

Of course I re-used "tmpFather" and "tmpGranpa" variables. Ok. They are temporary, I don't care.

Now, in child1.js (which is our entry point), I add the check of child 2

```
(child1.js)

console.log('Check obj1 result: '+obj1.myname);
console.log('Check obj2 result: '+obj2.myname);
console.log('Check granpa was not overridden: '+granpa.myname);
console.log('Check father was not overridden: '+father.myname);
```

Output is

```
Check obj1 result: Child 2
Check obj2 result: Child 2
Check granpa was not overridden: Granpa
Check father was not overridden: Father
```

Why?
Is there a way to build such objects (obj1 and obj2) extending father and granpa, leaving the original objects (father, granpa, child1, child2) untouched, and without having all the properties messed up?

Thank you in advance.

---

**The "Object.assign()" suggest**

The problem with Object.assign is that it seems to not add missing properties, like $.extend does. See this example

```
var granpa = {
    myname: 'Granpa',
    mydata: {age: 80, salary: undefined}
};

var father = {
    myname: 'Father',
    mydata: {age: 50, salary: 30000}
};

var child1 = {
    myname: 'Child 1',
    mydata: {salary: 15000} /* Note: "age" property missing!!! */
};

var newObj = Object.assign({}, granpa, father, child1);

console.log(newObj.mydata.age);
```

The output is

```
undefined
```

I need such behaviour, because "age" is like a setting which can be or not overridden. If child1 has "age", then it should override father's and granpa's, if "age" is missing in child1 (as in the example), child1 should inherit father's age.

$.extend works like I need.

Comment: Have you looked into `Object.assign()` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Just do `$.extend` or `Object.assign` with an empty first argument: `$.extend({}, ....)` to avoid mutations of existing objects.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.extend()` takes multiple objects and concatenates the properties together. Therefore, the second object, if it contains the same properties, will override the previously set properties. [jQuery.extend() Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/).

Instead, use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) passing in your granpa, child and father objects. This will leave each one separate and not touch what was already done.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. Please see "The "Object.assign()" suggest" in edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the correct answer is

```
var obj1 = $.extend(true, {}, tmpGranpa, tmpFather, child1);
```